# "There will/seems to be" or "There will/seems to have"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

Should I write:

> There will *be* a meeting in the afternoon.
>
> There seems to *be* a problem with the computer.

or

> There will *have* a meeting in the afternoon.
>
> There seems to *have* a problem with the computer.

I hear most people saying the former, "there will *be*" and "there will be". But for some reason, I have found "will be" to be illogical. I find "have a" makes more sense because "there" will not become a meeting but we can expect that we will *have* a meeting.

Similarly, "seems to be a problem" sounds like it is becoming a problem while "have a problem" sounds like it is *having* a problem, which is closer to the meaning.

Which one is grammatically correct and logically sound?

Comment: You mean 'there seems to have been a problem?'

Comment: Both the sentences in the second instance with 'have a' are wrong, I can say that much...

Comment: @AndySemyonov Are they wrong in terms of grammar? How are they wrong?

Comment: Yes they're both wrong. I think your question in the beginning was about choosing between 'will be' or 'will have been.' Did someone edit it incorrectly?

Comment: 'There will have been a meeting..' and 'There will have been a problem...' would be correct grammatically.

Comment: @AndySemyonov I edited it after recalling that I have problems with *seems to be/have* too. So, "there will be a meeting" is the correct way of saying it? And actually, even though "there will have been a meeting" is grammatically correct, what does it mean in exact? I can't quite comprehend the whole statement as "There will have been a meeting in the afternoon."

Comment: When you say 'There will be a meeting in the afternoon,' you're absolutely certain that there 'will' be a meeting, you're looking at a future event from present. However, when you say 'There will have been a meeting,' you're looking back from a point when it 'will have happened' but it didn't. Maybe some hindrance arose and therefore it had to be cancelled.

Comment: The fundamental point here is whether you use the verb *to be* or the verb *to have*. If you are stating that a meeting will take place then *there will be* is the way to go. *There will be a meeting*, *there will be people at the meeting*, *there will be tables, chairs etc*. But if you are stating that someone or something is going to arrange that meeting then it is *We will have a meeting*, *John had an idea* etc.

Comment: A slight correction, @AndySemyonov. [Future Perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_perfect) is a the construction used for an event that **is expected to happen before** a time even farther in the future. E.g.:  *By the time you get off the plane, **there will have been** a meeting at the office.* Meaning: The future meeting will happen before you get off the plane even farther in the future.

Comment: @ScotM Right, I think I confused it with 'would have been.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first set is correct.

E.g., the first sentence shows **the existence of a meeting** in the afternoon, thus "be" is natural.

**The 2nd set is totally wrong.**

Don't try to re-invent or rethink the English language. At your level, find good models and **follow** them.

You could say,  using "have":

*We **/will have/will be having/** a meeting in the afternoon.*

*We seem **to have** a problem with the computer **each time we reboot it**.*

*We seem **to be having** a problem with the computer **/right now/for several days now/.***